# Is there an alternative to doing nested GROUP BYs?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, netezza

I 'm trying to find IDs that are assigned to multiple locations. Note IDs of 26 and 28 have multiple records, but with the same `loc` so I don't want them in the result set. Data can look like this:

```
Id | loc
-------
23 | A
23 | B
24 | A
25 | A
26 | A
26 | A
27 | A
27 | B
28 | B
28 | B
29 | A
29 | B
```

What I'm currently doing is:

```
Select id
FROM (
    Select id, loc, count(*) 
    from tbl 
    GROUP BY id, loc 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
    ) grped
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

I'm trying to return these IDs:

```
Id 
--
23
27
29
```

Comment: Your sample code does not answer the question suggested in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for IDs with more than one loc:

```
select id
from tbl 
group by id
having count(distinct loc) > 1;
```

Comment: Great, this was what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the goal of "I'm trying to find IDs that are assigned to multiple locations."

A simple way uses one `group by`:

```
select id
from tbl
group by id
having min(loc) <> max(loc);
```

Note:  this is slightly different from your logic, because it ignores `NULL` values, whereas your version treats `NULL` locs as just another value.  The above can be modified to take this into account:

```
select id
from tbl
group by id
having (min(loc) <> max(loc)) or
       (min(loc) is not null and count(loc) <> count(*))
```